# DropDownlist.SelectedIndexChanged is not firing for the first time

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, updatepanel, selectedindexchanged

I am facing a strange issue.

I have a dropdownlist inside an update panel like this

```
<asp:DropDownList onchange="saveSurface();" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSportTeam1_SelectedIndexChanged"
           Width="150px" AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddlSportTeam1" runat="server" EnableViewState="True">
```

The problem is when I change the value of dropdown for the first time it doesn't go to `OnSelectedIndexChanged`, however it does go to `Page_Init` and `Page_Load` events.

And then for any subsequent changes in dropown values works perfectly fine.

So only for the first time it is not calling selected index changed event!

I searched and found that sometimes enabling viewstate makes it work but for my case even that doesn't. I tried both enabling and disabling view state.

Any idea of this weird behavior?

Comment: Are you binding the list in !IsPostBack check?

Comment: Could you edit your question and post all of your markup and code?

Comment: Is your update panel set to update conditionally?

Comment: @Camilo - Yes. I tried "Always" also, but no luck :(

Comment: Try removing the update panel and see if that affects anything

Comment: I am facing the same problem and still not know how to fix it :W

Comment: Check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650734/dropdownlist-selectedindexchanged-event-is-not-firing

Comment: Check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650734/dropdownlist-selectedindexchanged-event-is-not-firing